# How do I change URL behavior for an Android browser

Tags: android, mobile, android-intent, browser

Suppose there is a link to a tweet on some web page. When I click it, I want to view in my Twitter client app instead of inside the browser. How can I achieve that? Can I develop extensions to my Android browser (the stock one, Chrome, Dolphin, Firefox, etc)? Or there's another way to do that?

Another example is when I click on a LinkedIn profile link in my email, and it opens up a page saying "Get the App" and "Go the profile". How can I make the browser be aware that I already have the app, and it should really redirect me to the app and show the profile there? This probably is not about the browser but about the website and the individual apps. Let me know.

Update #1: I'm not clicking the link in some app developed by myself. It will be some app that I don't have control of.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a URL in your app you need to take a look at [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). These will allow you to respond to a URL when the user clicks a link. In the case of Twitter the following would work,

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_VIEW"/>
    <data android:host="twitter.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This way then the user attempts to open any twitter.com URL they will be presented with the app chooser.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But what if it is not my app. Say, the stock gmail app.

Comment: Ah ok read your question first thing in the morning and took a mis-cue. I guess a dolphin extension might be the order of the day. If your app responds to the links though it should intercept the links from other apps, although you can't force the handling.